# How do you tell if a checkbox is selected in Selenium for VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

How do you tell if a checkbox at a web page is selected in Selenium for VBA? Im willing to check if a checkbox is selected or not to either click on a link or another. Following is the screenshot of the page inspection which i want to check if the checkbox os selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a good answer when there is no code to work with but this should do the trick.

```
Function isGradIDChecked(Document As Object) As Boolean
      Dim CheckBox As Object
    Set CheckBox = Document.querySelector("input#grdAse_ct113_chkAprovDP")
    If Not CheckBox Is Nothing Then
        isGradIDChecked = CheckBox.Checked
    Else
        Debug.Print "input#grdAse_ct113_chkAprovDP Not Found"
    End If
End Function
```